# Почему возникает ImportError Django

Tags: django, django-cms

Мне скинули проект сайта, мне нужно запустить его для начала хотя бы на локалке, но нормально не выходит что-то...

При попытке запуска выдает следующую ошибку, которая, как я понимаю, вообще не связана с имеющимся у меня кодом, возможно, какой-то конфликт версий.

Django 1.11.17

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0509F300>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 23, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cms\admin\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    plugin_pool.plugin_pool.discover_plugins()
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cms\plugin_pool.py", line 45, in discover_plugins
    autodiscover_modules('cms_plugins')
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\djangocms_text_ckeditor\cms_plugins.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.urls import re_path, reverse
ImportError: cannot import name 're_path' from 'django.urls' (C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\__init__.py)
```

Заранее спасибо за уделенное время!

Comment: Django слишком старый

Comment: django 2.0 имеет уже другой синтаксис, здесь используется django<2.0 поэтому использую последнюю версию до 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Функция re_path, доступна с версии Django >= 2.0
в 1.11 можно использовать url() из того-же пакета, он поддерживает регулярные выражения.

Comment: Использована именно url(), ошибка возникает в файле cms_plugins.py

Comment: @ЕгорКузнецов значит у вас наоборот Django CMS слишком новый, ставьте старый